# Abbreviating in SQL versus not abbreviating

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, select

I'm in an SQL course for the first time and was having trouble with writing a query using the `leebooks.sql` file. I came across a solution, however I am curious because the solution I found has all the tables and columns abbreviated. When I tried to rewrite the query without abbreviations as my professor prefers, I get an error saying table doesn't exist.  I thought I rewrote it correctly, the query with the abbreviations works fine. I don't know where to upload the SQL file on here if needed?  Here are the queries:

With Abbreviations:

```
SELECT b.Title, bo.OrderDate,bo.OrderID
FROM BOOKS b
LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDER_ITEMS oi 
  ON b.BookID = oi.BookID
LEFT OUTER JOIN BOOK_ORDER bo 
  ON oi.OrderID = bo.OrderID
ORDER BY oi.BOOKID DESC;
```

Without Abbreviations:

```
SELECT BOOKS.Title, BOOK_ORDER.OrderDate, BOOK_ORDER.OrderID 
FROM BOOKS 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDER_ITEMS.OrderID 
  ON BOOKS.BookID = ORDER_ITEMS.BookID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN BOOK_ORDER 
  ON ORDER_ITEMS.OrderID = BOOK_ORDER.OrderID 
ORDER BY ORDER_ITEMS.BookID DESC;
```

I don't understand why the second one doesn't work while the first one does if they're basically the same thing.  What am I missing?

Comment: You have "LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDER_ITEMS.OrderID" you should have "LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDER_ITEMS"

Answer (score 2):

Joins should be performed on tables, not on columns. Your clause `LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDER_ITEMS.OrderID` should read `LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDER_ITEMS`. The full query, without table aliases:

```
SELECT BOOKS.Title, BOOK_ORDER.OrderDate, BOOK_ORDER.OrderID
FROM BOOKS 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDER_ITEMS ON BOOKS.BookID = ORDER_ITEMS.BookID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN BOOK_ORDER ON ORDER_ITEMS.OrderID = BOOK_ORDER.OrderID 
ORDER BY ORDER_ITEMS.BookID DESC;
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't see that.  Guess my eyes aren't used to starting at stuff like this for so long.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

'Aliases', whether `'table' AS tableAlias` or column (`table.column` AS `columnAlias`)  are text substitution.

There was a table name (`ORDER_ITEMS`) replaced with a column name (`ORDER_ITEMS.OrderID`). i.e `JOIN ORDER_ITEMS.OrderID` instead of: JOIN `ORDER_ITEMS`...

What you have, with 'aliases' and I added the 'AS' keyword to try and make it clear.

```
SELECT `b`.title, 
       `bo`.orderdate, 
       `bo`.orderid 
FROM   books AS `b`
       LEFT OUTER JOIN order_items AS `oi` 
                    ON `b`.bookid = `oi`.bookid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN book_order  AS `bo` 
                    ON `oi`.orderid = `bo`.orderid 
ORDER  BY `oi`.bookid DESC;
```

This is valid SQL. I have used 'AS' and backtick to highlight the 'alias'.

List of table aliases:

- `b` => *`books`*
- `oi` => *`order_items`*
- `bo` => *`book_order`*

So, replace all the `table aliases` with the `table names`. Here I use backticks around table names to indicate substitution.

```
SELECT `books`.title, 
       `book_order`.orderdate, 
       `book_order`.orderid 
FROM   `books` 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `order_items` 
                    ON `books`.bookid = `order_items`.bookid 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN `book_order` 
                    ON `order_items`.orderid = `book_order`.orderid 
ORDER  BY `order_items`.bookid DESC;
```

It is text substitution for table names or column names.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure if there were certain rules to the abbreviating, that makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: So with this one:                                                                          SELECT BC.FirstName ||','|| BC.LastName AS "Customer Name" , BO.OrderID FROM BOOK_CUSTOMER BC NATURAL JOIN BOOK_ORDER BO WHERE BO.ShipDate is NOT NULL ORDER BY CustomerID ASC;  with no abbreviations would it be                                                        SELECT BOOK_CUSTOMER.FirstName ||','|| BOOK_CUSTOMER.LastName AS "Customer Name" , BOOK_ORDER.OrderID 
FROM BOOK_CUSTOMER NATURAL JOIN BOOK_ORDER
WHERE BOOK_ORDER.ShipDate is NOT NULL                                    ORDER BY CustomerID ASC;

Comment: Also worth mentioning - once you set an alias you cannot use "Table.Column" anymore, you need to use "Alias.Column". Or just [Column] works in both cases as long as there is no ambiguity.

Comment: I figured it, that did work.  Thanks for the help though.